# Adding Dropdown with Dynamic data [Picker] Also Getting data Using MVVM And Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm

My Code
I went To creat Dynamic data (Dropdown)[Picker] but not display Data

ViewModel.cs File

```
List m_city = new List();
public List get_Cities { get; set; }

public void GetCity()
{
    m_city = Database.DB.All().ToList();
    var city_names = m_city.Select(x => new { x.Id , x.Name})
                           .Distinct()
                           .ToList();
    foreach (var item in city_names)
    {
        City get_City = new Models.City();
        get_City.Id = item.Id;
        get_City.Name = item.Name;
        get_Cities.Add(get_City);
    }
}
```

Xaml File:

```
<Picker x:Name="City"  BindingContext="{Binding get_Cities}">
```

Comment: I'm afraid that's not how `Picker`s work in Xamarin.Forms. Consider using [XLab's BindablePicker](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms/Controls/BindablePicker.cs) if you're using stable, or bind your get_Cities to [Picker's ItemsSource property](https://blog.xamarin.com/new-bindable-picker-control-for-xamarin-forms/) if you're using the pre-release version

Comment: Thanks For Suggestion...But Not a Xamarin Form .. Using MVVM And C#